# Methods that use completion blocks and return an object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method that inits the object and it has a completion block: `typedef void(^initCompletionHandler)(BOOL succesful);`

In this method I want to call the handler but I am not sure how to do it because if I call it before the return the object won't be finished initialising which is used immediately in the next line. I also obviously can't call the handler after the return. i,e:

```
   if(haveError){
            handler(NO);
        }
        else{

            handler(YES);
        }
        return self;
```

Is there any way I can return and call the handler at the same time?

Comment: I would suggest you create a class factory method and use that rather than alloc/init

Comment: @Paulw11 I'd suggest that even if you implement factory method, you might not want to initiate the process that would result in the completion `handler` being called.

Comment: Yeah I'm not much of a fan of the OPs approach really - the handler should be invoked from a method called on the object after initialisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. I'm unclear as to why you say "because ... the return object won't be finished initialising." You're doing the initialization, so just ensure it finishes all of the associated initialization before calling that `handler`. If the issue is that the caller won't have a valid reference to that object yet, you could always include a reference to it in the parameter of the block, e.g.

   ```
   typedef void(^initCompletionHandler)(MyObject object, BOOL succesful);
   ```

   and then supply that parameter, e.g.:

   ```
   if (haveError){
       handler(self, NO);
   } else {
       handler(self, YES);
   }
   ```
2. Also, you say "I obviously can't call the handler after the return". But you can. You could just do a `dispatch_async`, if you wanted:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       if (haveError){
           handler(NO);
       } else {
           handler(YES);
       }
   });
   return self;
   ```

   That's a little inelegant, as if you call it from another thread, you have some potential race conditions that you might have to coordinate/synchronize, but you get the idea: You don't have to call the `handler` synchronously.

Having made both of those observations, I must confess that I'm not a fan of having `init` actually launching some asynchronous process and having its own completion block. I'd be inclined to make those two different steps. If you look at the Cocoa API, Apple has largely shifted away from this pattern themselves, generally having one method for instantiation, and another for starting the asynchronous process.

Comment: You're right, thank for the comments. Does't really make sense putting a completion block in something that needs to return an object. I moved the asynchronous process out of the init method into it's own separate one. Works fine now and much clearer.